# Batch Script drag and drop folder convert images with ImageMagick

Tags: batch-file, imagemagick, batch-processing, photos

Firstly I've tried looking everywhere, and was unsuccessful. I am inexperienced and appreciate any help at all. I'm trying to write a script to drag a folder onto a batch file, which will then convert all images in that folder to jpgs, using ImageMagick. I can see it's very possible to execute the script on the command line, that all works fine. But to drag a folder is giving me issues. I can drag many files onto the script and it converts fine:

```
convert %* %1.jpg
```

that works great. I can also drag a folder, and it will convert the images inside, but rename then as the name of the folder, one directory higher, like so:

```
@set SOURCE=%1
convert %SOURCE%\* %SOURCE%.jpg
```

I imagine i need a for loop performing the convert on every file in the folder. But I have run into problems. I'm unsure where to put quotes, and what variables to use, and how to overcome spaces. I imagine something like this...

```
for %%f in (%SOURCE%\*) do ( convert %%f "%SOURCE%\%%f.jpg" )
```

But yeah, I'm at a loss. I'm trying this little project both to learn, and also to help my dad convert large amounts of his photos quickly.

Comment: Oh no! Someone responded with an answer but with recursion, and now it's gone :(
Does anyone have any idea how you would modify Rodney's script adding recursion? Sorry if I asked this in the wrong place. I know it's with the /R switch, but can't quite get it happening...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like ImageMagick can take multiple input arguments and one output argument, but to simplify it with one file at a time try the following.  Your loop looks right but the ~ changes below will handle quotes.

You may also want to change the %%a* match to be particular files so you don't catch existing jpgs or non-image files, e.g. for %%f in (%%a*.png %%a*.gif) do ...

Finally, add an "echo" in front of the two convert lines so you can do a test run.

```
@echo off

rem Loops through arguments. If a file converts it to a jpg.  If a directory
rem converts files in that directory to jpgs.  Assumes a program "convert".

set count=0
for %%a in (%*) do (
  if exist %%a (
    if exist %%a\ (
      rem Directory, loop through contents
      for %%f in (%%a\*) do (
        convert "%%f" "%%~a\%%~nf.jpg"
        set /a count+=1
      )
    ) else (
      rem File, just convert
      convert "%%~a" "%%~na.jpg"
      set /a count+=1
    )    
  ) else (
    echo Skipping non-existent %%~a
  )
)

echo Converted %count% files

pause
```

Comment: That is perfect Rodney. Really appreciate your comments in the script too, helps me to understand. Thanks for taking the time to help out.

Comment: Maybe using powershell script too.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite what you want; this creates a new directory within the original directory to save the modified photos into:

```
:: Create the new directory 
md %1\resized 

:: Resize and save the new version
for %%f in (%1\*.jpg) do ( convert "%%f" -thumbnail 800x800 "%1\resized\%%~nf.jpg" )
```

Comment: I did not read your question properly and my code is ONLY reading jpg images and is then resizing them before saving.